# How to show validation error like the error when i miss required field?

Tags: notifications, odoo, sweetalert

I'm new with odoo 11, I want to show a custom error popup but I want to show it like the popup error displayed when we miss a required field and this is not possible with ValidationError.
Is that possible ? If not, is it possible to use JavaScript api for notification like sweet alert ?

Answer (score 2):

you can follow the below method.

```
@api.constrains('field_name')
def _check_field_name(self):
    for record in self:
        if not record.field_name: # or your conditions
        raise ValidationError(_('Error COntext'))
```

First of ALL, you cant save the form without filling the required field. If you try to save you will get a warning ant cant save.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can raise an alert using **ValidationError** but for this you need to override the create and write method and need to check this field's value and if it is empty you can raise ValidationError alert.

Answer (score 1):

On Odoo 11, if you want to

- raise an Error by Python

  ```py
  # Import the exceptions from odoo
  from odoo import exceptions

  # Then somewhere in your code
  raise exceptions.ValidationError('Your error message here!')

  # Or more generic error by
  raise exceptions.UserError('This is not a ValidationError.')
  ```
- do_warn (notification) by Javascript

  ```js
  // Maybe inside your Widget
  var self = this;
  self.do_warn('Your title', 'Your message')
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this with validationerror because framework will not pass the values till it satisfied, so create & write method will not get called.

You need to make changes in JavaScript & change the behavior as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the same error as when you miss required fields using the following javascript code:

```
this.do_warn(_t("The following fields are invalid :"), "msg");
```

You can also use `SweetAlert`, just add the javascript to your module.